# Spring AMQP. Deal Letter Exchange. Send message to the original queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

In my system, I use Topic Exchanges with lots of consumer queues. Each queue has it's own non-unique routing key (f.e. 'add.#' for all new entities or just '#' to consume all events).


I want to add support for retrying failed messages with some delay. The biggest issue that I see with Dead Letter Exchange approach is to send a message directly to the queue in which it failed. Routing keys for Queues are not unique, and even if I resubmit a message to the Exchange with the original routing key, it will be consumed by other queues.

 

One solution is having a "retry" exchange and every application will be subscribed to it with unique routing key (f.e. original queue name). But it sounds too complicated and I want to hide this infrastructure complexity from developers.

 

I came up with the idea to have a filter that will check the 'x-death' header, get the first queue (the queue where the error occurred in a first place), and process a message only for the appropriate queue. Otherwise - acknowledge the message.

 

Is it possible to implement this behavior with Spring AMQP? I'm looking into **MessagePostProcessor**, but how to Acknowledge a message from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really worry about only the target queue, so you need to consider a variant with republishing in the `default exchange` which has these abilities:

> The default exchange is implicitly bound to every queue, with a routing key equal to the queue name. It is not possible to explicitly bind to, or unbind from the default exchange. It also cannot be deleted.

Pay attention to the `routing key equal to the queue name` part. I would consider to deal with a `AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE` and use its value as a routing key for republishing to the default exchange (`""`) during retry process.